# Find the height, $h$, for the maximum area of the curved surface of a right circular cylinder

Tags: calculus

Find the height, $h$, for the maximum area of the curved surface of a right circular cylinder with base radius $r$ which can fit inside a sphere of radius $R$.

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to start and whether i need to work any angle in the solution too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=2{\pi}rh$

Using Pythagoras, $$r^2=R^2-\frac {h^2}{4}$$ therefore $$A^2=4{\pi}^2r^2h^2=4{\pi}^2\left(R^2-\frac{h^2}{4}\right)h^2$$
Now differentiate:
$$2A\frac{dA}{dh}=4{\pi}^2\left(2R^2h-h^3\right)=0$$ and get $h=R\sqrt{2}$

Comment: thanks for the solution but would you mind giving a little explanation about what you did. i would very much appreciate it

Comment: @saufi: is that OK?

Comment: yeah. that's great. cheers

Comment: @saufi: you're welcome